# Plotting the number of active objects over time

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have data on two types of government policies, type 1 and type 0. These are active over different points in time, and sometimes multiple are active at the same time. I want to plot their start to end dates.

I'm working with the following dataframe:

```
START<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-13 01:40:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT"))

END<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-09-28 13:00:00 MDT"))

TYPE<-c(1, 0, 1,  1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)

DF<-data.frame(START, END, TYPE)
```

Then I try to plot this series, with a basic ggplot:

```
ggplot(DF)+
    geom_segment(aes(x=as.POSIXct(as.character(START)),
                     xend=as.POSIXct(as.character(END)),
                     y=TYPE,
                     yend=TYPE), size=2)
```

[This plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqsrH.png) is unsatisfactory however. What I'm aiming for is for each separate activation of policy type to correspond with a single line. This way, one could see how many of each type of policies were active at the same time, [such as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Ega.jpg). What ggplot code could produce such a plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want `geom_linerange()` as this allows the `position = position_dodge()` parameter.

Dates are tricky things and for reasons I haven't worked out it seems to work when I convert the date columns to character strings. Your data may also be hard to visualise as the range in intervals is very large ranging from 1 to 757 hours?

I made this graph only down to the resolution of days but I hope this helps.

Note that it is super janky as I add in a bunch of dummy observations to make the spread of dates reflect actual time and I then just make them transparent in the plot. There must be a way to integrate dodging and time.

[image]

```
library(dplyr)   
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% 
   mutate(START = format(START, "%Y-%m-%d"),
          END = format(END, "%Y-%m-%d"),
          color = "black") %>% 
   bind_rows(tibble(START = format(seq(min(c(DF$START, DF$END)), max(c(DF$START, DF$END)), by = "days"),  "%Y-%m-%d"), 
               END = format(seq(min(c(DF$START, DF$END)), max(c(DF$START, DF$END)), by = "days"),  "%Y-%m-%d"),
               TYPE = 0, 
               color = "white")) %>%

ggplot(aes(x = factor(TYPE), y = END, ymin = START, ymax = END, color = color)) +
  geom_linerange(position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#00000000")) +
  coord_flip()
```

---

Another option would be to make the y-axis continuous with an arbitrary ID number and then sort by policy.

```
DF %>% 
  arrange(TYPE) %>% 
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = END, ymin = START, ymax = END, color = factor(TYPE))) +
  geom_linerange(size = 2) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

You could spread separate the IDs if you wanted and remove Y-axis labels